# OllyDbg: Automatically extract string when breakpoint is hit

Tags: ollydbg, debuggers

Given a breakpoint at an expression `MOV EDI, EAX`, how can you automatically log/write to file the referenced string whenever the breakpoint is hit?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Select the `MOV EDI, EAX` instruction and press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> to open the **Conditional log** breakpoint window.

In that window, specify `eax` as the expression, set **Pause program** to **Never**, and set **Log value of expressions** to **Always**:

[image: Conditional log]

Press the **OK** button, run your program, and now the referenced string will get logged to OllyDbg's log window whenever that instruction is hit.

Comment: With regard to blabb's answer below, yes, my answer above was for OllyDbg 2.

Comment: Is there a to way log in case of some memory DWORD has changed?

Answer (score 0):

in odbg version 1.10
that will only `log eax` not the string
in the expression box put either `STRING [EAX]` or `UNICODE [eax]`  as the case may be
or with plain eax select `pointer to ascii or unicode string` in `decode expression as` dropdown box to log strings

Log data, item 0
 Message=eax  = 1001590  [eax]  = 74636868  string [eax]  = hhctrl.ocx  unicode [eax] =

`odbg 210` will decode expression automatically

```
01012475  INT3: plain eax = 1001590 ASCII "hhctrl.ocx"
                dword ptr eax = 74636868 (1952671848.)
                ascii string ptr eax = hhctrl.ocx
```